# Issue with Serializing list in Django framework and Vue JS

Tags: django, django-models, vuejs2, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am want to serialize the list during update, example making patch call to update below user profile with "cuisine"

Get call

```
**http://localhost:8000/api/v1/chef/rayees/details**


    {
        "user": {
            "pk": 2,
            "username": "rayees",
            "email": "rayees.xxxx@yahoo.co.in",
            "first_name": "Rayees",
            "last_name": "xxxx",
            "user_type": "Chef"
        },
        "first_name": "Rayees",
        "last_name": "xxx",
        "bio": "TEST BIO",
        "chef_cost": "10.00",
        "serve_type": "Non-Veg",
        "cuisine": [
            "South Indian", 
            "North Indian"
        ]

    }
```

Here is my serializer class,  i think "serializers.SerializerMethodField()" is read only one and "cuisine" not getting updated during patch operation , If want to serialize both get and patch, what should i do here

```
class ChefProfileDetails(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    chef_date = AvailabilityDetails(many=True, read_only=True)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.first_name', read_only=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.last_name', read_only=True)
    cities = CitySerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    cuisine = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    user = UserDetailsSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Chef
        fields = ('user', 'first_name', 'last_name', 
                  'bio', 'chef_cost', 'serve_type', 'cuisine', 'chef_date', 'cities')

    def get_cuisine(self, obj):
        cuisine_list = []
        for i in obj.cuisine.all():
            cuisine_list.append(i.cuisine)
        return cuisine_list
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one-to-many connection between Chef and Cuisine models, so try to use RelatedField:

```
class ChefProfileDetails(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cuisines = serializers.RelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Chef
        fields = ('user', 'first_name', 'last_name', 
                  'bio', 'chef_cost', 'serve_type',
                  'cuisine', 'chef_date', 'cities')
```

I think that should work.

Comment: it fails

```
  File "/Users/rayeesn/Documents//venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 589, in to_representation
    field_name=self.field_name,
NotImplementedError: RelatedField.to_representation() must be implemented for field . If you do not need to support write operations you probably want to subclass `ReadOnlyField` instead.
2020-01-17 07:17:57,105 raven.contrib.django.client.DjangoClient INFO     Raven is not configured (logging is disabled). Please see the documentation for more information.
```

Comment: @RayeesNamathponnan oops, I think it should be StringRelatedField then :D

Comment: My model for cuisine is many to many 

 cuisine = models.ManyToManyField('Cuisine')

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you need by defining a Custom Field and then provide your definition of getter and setter in `to_representation()` and `to_internal_value()` respectively.

Code:

```
class CuisineField(serializers.Field):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        cuisine_list = []
        for i in value:
            cuisine_list.append(i.cuisine)
        return cuisine_list


    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        ""
         Do whatever you want to do in patch
        ""
```

And then define cuisine as CuisineField in your serializer as

`cuisine = CuisineField()`

Refer DRF [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields) for custom fields